# Animating translate percentages on Android Native Browser (4.x)

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, android-browser

I'm working on a small web-app that uses the popular sidebar interaction pattern. When using CSS3 animations to translate the sidebar into view, the animation scrolls out of view but stops at the correct position in Android's native browser.

The animation code is quite simple:

```
#wrapper > #off-canvas { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
}
#wrapper > #off-canvas.off { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(80%, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate(80%, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate(80%, 0);
         -o-transform: translate(80%, 0);
            transform: translate(80%, 0);
}
```

You can see the behaviour in the JS-Fiddle I made. The code is a bit messy, but the behaviour is clearly buggy. (Of course you need an Android device in order to reproduce the error)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/67skS/1/)

- When animating the "left" property, everything works fine.
- When using `transform: translate` with px values, everything works fine.

Has anyone else experienced problems with this and found a work around?
**I'd like to use a method which supports hardware acceleration to improve the app's performance.**

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The native android browser (not Chrome) over-scrolls.  It does not like the `translate` property.  I was able to fix it with just using `margin-left` instead.

```
#wrapper > #off-canvas.off { 
    margin-left:80%;
}
```

[Here's a plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/NT7a1vJAd9UUDo1IfPh5)

Comment: Although your solution fixes the problem, I'd prefer one that supports hardware acceleration like `translate`.
I already mentioned in my post that I'm aware of the fact, that things like `margin` and `left` are animated properly.